# C:\Program Files\MSBuid\Novell\Novell.MOnoDroid.Csharp.targets was not found

Tags: android, xamarin.android

when i am creating new android project from visual studio 2010 it gives the below message.

C:\Program Files\MSBuid\Novell\Novell.MOnoDroid.Csharp.targets was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disks.

How do i overcome this error.

Comment: Did you "confirm that the path in the declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk" ? Or are you trying to avoid using this file ?

Comment: i have checked. there is no Novell.MOnoDroid.Csharp.targets at that location, nor in program files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a bad install, uninstall and reinstall and try again.

Comment: This did not solve my issue :(
I have been busting my head on this for three days :(